# Executing Qt patch on Mac

Tags: git, qt, patch

I am compiling `qt5.7.1` on mac but got some errors, which are known bugs and there is patch available [here](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/225086/). How can i apply this patch on mac? I tried this command

`git fetch https://codereview.qt-project.org/qt/qt3d refs/changes/86/225086/6 && git checkout FETCH_HEAD`

but got error

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Any idea, how to apply patch to qt?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an existing qt5.git clone:

1. `cd` to the location of that qt5.git repo.
2. Run `git submodule init qt3d`.
3. Run `git submodule update qt3d`.
4. `cd` to `qt3d`.
5. Run `git fetch https://codereview.qt-project.org/qt/qt3d refs/changes/86/225086/6 && git checkout FETCH_HEAD`.
6. Use your existing build to run qmake: `/Users/foo/dev/qt5-build/qtbase/bin/qmake /path/to/qt3d/`

If you have existing Qt 5 sources, but not a repo:

1. Go to http://code.qt.io/cgit/ to find the qt3d repo. There's a search bar in the top right.
2. Copy one of the URLs; for example: https://code.qt.io/qt/qt3d.git
3. Clone the repo from that URL: `git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qt3d.git`
4. Build the module. See step 6 above or the link below.

A comprehensive set of instructions can be found here:

https://wiki.qt.io/Building_Qt_5_from_Git